# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to fetch data based on condition and role

Tags: asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I have Leave Application. It consists of these roles, and a user can only have one role.

The roles are Admin, GeneralUser, Accountant and HOD.

I want to fetch data based on the Role of the logged in user. I have this code:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<LeaveApproval>> GetEmployeeLeaveAsync(PagingFilter filter)
{
    var userName = _currentUserService.UserName;
    var getUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
    var loggedUserRole = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(getUser);
    var loggedUserRoleName = loggedUserRole[0].ToString();
    var userDepartmentId = _dbContext.EmployeeUsers.Where(u => u.User.UserName == userName).Select(m => m.BankBranch.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (loggedUserRoleName == "Accountant")
    {
        var datas = _dbContext.LeaveApprovals
                    .Where(m => (bool)m.Leave.IsApproved == false && m.Leave.DepartmentId == EmployeeUsers)
                    .Include(x => x.Leave)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);
        return datas;
    }
    else if (loggedUserRoleName == "HOD")
    {
        var datas = _dbContext.LeaveApprovals
                    .Where(m => (bool)m.Leave.IsApproved == false && m.Leave.BankBranchId == userBranchId)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);
        return datas;
    }
    // Other Roles (Admin, GeneralUser)
    else
    {
        var datas = _dbContext.LeaveApprovals
                    .Where(m => (bool)m.Leave.IsApproved == false)
                    .Include(x => x.Leave)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt);
        return datas;
    }
}
```

From the code above, **IF** AND **ELSE IF** are not fetch fetching any result. Yet they have data. Instead it executes the **ELSE statement**. I checked and the conditions are okay.

Why is it not working for Accountant and HOD roles?

What could have been wrong and how do I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: since you are returning an IQueryable, did u force execute thr query by using FirstOrDefaultAsync() or ToListAsync()?

Comment: @thanzeel - How and where do I do that?

Comment: you have to do it in the calling method `GetEmployeeLeaveAsync(PagingFilter filter)`. does your code go inside the if (loggedUserRoleName == "Accountant") condition?

Comment: @thanzeel - Are talking about this as in the code above?       var userDepartmentId = _dbContext.EmployeeUsers.Where(u => u.User.UserName == userName).Select(m => m.BankBranch.Id).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: no, the caller of the method. Are you sure this  var loggedUserRoleName = loggedUserRole[0].ToString(); returns a string and not an object? did u check if the case sensivity?

Comment: @thanzeel - Yes, var loggedUserRoleName = loggedUserRole[0].ToString();.  When I comment  else if (loggedUserRoleName == "HOD") { .. and  else { ... and leave only if (loggedUserRoleName == "Accountant") I got this error:    Error CS0161 'AdminLeaveApprovalRepository.GetEmployeeLeaveAsync(PagingFilter)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: please produce a minimul repository to debug

Comment: @thanzeel - How do you mean? Can you explain

Comment: @thanzeel - When I added .ToListAsync(); at the end, I got this error:   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<Entities.LeaveApproval>>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Entities.LeaveApproval>'. An explicit conversion exists

Comment: checj what you are returnin from the method and the return type. the problem seems to be the return type

Comment: Hello, did you checked how the `HOD` value comes in run time? Have you check there is no issue in `alphabatic CASE`. In addition, could please have a look on [`Role based authorization`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0#adding-role-checks)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - Yes, I checked

Comment: Is there any mismatched there? If no then could you please your `database schema` in addition please share few valid demo data so that it can be reproduced. Would be great if you could include the full controller.